# Menu displaying on website

Tags: wordpress, menu, header, structure

I have problem in my website ([getsix.eu](http://getsix.eu)) with header menu structure, because not displayed correctly on Google Chrome web browser. On firefox my top menu displayed properly.

I see problem with "overflow: hidden;".

How to get around this problem?

Comment: You're going to need to give us more than this.  Please post some code, along with examples of the problem.  What you have posted is nowhere near enough to go on.

Comment: I mean this piece of code: '<ul class="sub-menu" style="overflow: hidden; display: none;">' This automatic add style 'overflow'

Answer (score 0):

In the css file, you can add at line 679 for class

> header .sub-menu

the property:

> overflow: visible!important;

Comment: I do not want to add it that way, because the effect menu appears after bad. You can do so using Firebug.

Comment: I added the code, and now please you see how it works. Faster background disappears and later subtitles.

Comment: Ok, you can add a hover property like this: `header .sub-menu:hover {overflow: visible!important;}`

Comment: I added but this is not working, you can check on getsix.eu :(

Comment: Now remove the `overflow: visible !important` property from `header .sub-menu` and keep it only for the :hover status